# Partición NTFS compartido con windows y linux, no aparecen archivos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, grub, ntfs

hace un par de semana compre un computador, tenía instalado Windows, le cree varias particiones y decidí no eliminar Windows así que junto a Windows instale Ubuntu en otra partición. He trabajo en Ubuntu estas dos últimas semanas, sin embargo, hoy inicié con Windows para modificar un archivo de office y tuve la sorpresa que en la partición Archivos no me aparece ningún archivo de los he estado almacenando en esta partición(ntfs) desde ubuntu, pude ver que aparece con espacio ocupado en la partición por lo que imagino que los archivos están ahí.

Ya no pude acceder a Ubuntu ya que el GRUB, fallo y ahora entro directo a Windows, no mi importa mucho eso, pero los archivos no los puedo perder por nada del mundo y más que todo necesito ver estos proyectos que tenía ahí tal cual.

Por favor si alguien sabe que puedo hacer.
Probé recuperar los archivos con Recuva no aparece nada.
Inicie desde Ubuntu Try para ver si aparecen los archivos en la partición y nada.
Intente recuperar el GRUB sin éxito.
Tengo una partición extra donde no tengo estos proyectos tan importantes y a este le di reparar desde Windows y aparecen archivos, pero sin extensión, tendría que cambiar la extensión uno por uno y esto no serviría con la partición Archivos ya que serían miles de archivos de los proyectos.

Comment: Hay dos posibilidades, la peor, es que hayas formateado el disco durante la instalación, lo único que puedes hacer, es buscar y renombrar todos los archivos, te recomiendo usar linux, ya que no necesita las extensiones para identificarlos, antes de ir por ese camino, te sugiero que uses un live-disc de **Linux Mint**, y con la utilidad **discos**, intentes reparar el sistema de archivos, porque esa y no otra?, he probado varias, y a la hora de entenderse con formatos de Windows y Linux, es la que me ha funcionado mejor.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata de un problema de programación, tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic]. Esta pregunta podría ser mejor recibida en [su].

Comment: ¿Puede ser un tema de permisos? En otras palabras, ¿los has buscado con un proceso elevado?